# How do corporate codes work in Amadeus Fligh Offers Search API?

Tags: json, amadeus

I'm working with Amadeus Flight Offers Search API and I'd like to use my client's corporate code in order to search offers including corp nego fares. I see there is a field for corporate codes in the schema, but corporate codes need to be loaded into an OID in order to work, and I'm not specifying an OID when calling the API. How will this work?

I have tried using some corporate codes that I know and no corporate fares have appeared. This is an example I have tried.

```
{
  "currencyCode": "EUR",
  "originDestinations": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "originLocationCode": "MAD",
      "destinationLocationCode": "NYC",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2019-09-01",
        "time": "10:00:00",
        "timeWindow" : "6H"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "originLocationCode": "NYC",
      "destinationLocationCode": "MIA",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2019-09-03",
        "time": "17:00:00",
        "timeWindow": "2H"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "originLocationCode": "MCO",
      "destinationLocationCode": "MAD",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2019-09-07",
        "time": "17:00:00",
        "timeWindow": "6H"
      }
    }
  ],
  "travelers": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "travelerType": "ADULT",
      "fareOptions": [
        "STANDARD"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sources": [
    "GDS", "PYTON"
  ],
  "searchCriteria": {
    "maxFlightOffers": 50,
    "pricingOptions" : {
        "corporateCodes" : ["000001"]
    },
    "flightFilters": {
        "connectionRestriction":
        {
            "airportChangeAllowed" : false,
            "maxNumberOfConnections" : 1
        }
      }
  }
}
```

The result is all published fares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Self-Service, we only offer public fares. Negotiated or private fares are only accessible to our Enterprise users. The reference documentation is not very clear about it, the API is still in beta and we will use your feedback to improve it.